# Exotic bold font

Tags: fonts

I am trying to figure out how to type in the bold font as the 'Ku(X)' in the image below. It seems to be skinner than mathbf or textbf and bolder than regular font. Any help would be appreciated!
[image]

Comment: Please, do you have taken your image? Have you a pdf?

Comment: The question of @Sebastiano makes me realize that there is a trick that you can use in some situations. I believe you are reading _Some remarks on Fano threefolds of index two and stability conditions_ by Pertusi and Yang (it is the only article I found on Google with this sentence). It is available on [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.02798). Notice, in the right panel, that you can download the article in "Other formats". Clicking on it leads to a page, in which the LaTeX source code can be downloaded. The source file confirms my answer: `\mathsf` is indeed used.

Comment: @user242429 Thank you very very much to have cited me :-)....:-)))...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like `\mathsf` to me.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}

stable objects in $\mathsf{Ku}(X)$ with torsion class

\end{document}
```